# Establishing the Trigonometric Idenitity

Tags: trigonometry

How do you establish the trigonometric identity?

$$\frac{(2\cos^2\theta-1)^2}{\cos^4\theta - \sin^4\theta} = 1-2\sin^2\theta$$

Comment: Use  $$\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can show this using the fact that $\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x=1$ and algebraic manipulation like so:
$$\frac{(2\cos^2 x-1)^2}{\cos^4 x-\sin^4 x}=\frac{(\cos^2 x+\cos^2 x-1)^2}{(\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x)(\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x)}=\frac{(\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x)^2}{(\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x)(\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x)}=\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x\\=\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x+\sin^2 x-\sin^2 x\ \text{(just "adding" 0 here)}\\=1-2\sin^2 x$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{(2\cos^2\theta-1)^2}{\cos^4\theta - \sin^4\theta}$$ Since $(2\cos^{2}\theta -1)^2= (\cos2\theta)^2$ This becomes:
$$\frac{({\cos(2\theta)})^2}{({\cos^2\theta})^2-({\sin^2\theta})^2}$$
This implies :$$\frac{({\cos(2\theta)})^2}{(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)(\sin^2\theta-\cos^2\theta)}$$
Now we know that $(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)= \cos(2\theta)$
This becomes $$\frac{({\cos(2\theta)})^2}{\cos{2\theta}}$$
$$=\cos{2\theta}=1-2\sin^2\theta$$

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

$a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$

${\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta=1}$

$\sin^4(x) – \cos^4(x) = 2\sin^2(x) – 1$
[Source](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/proving2.htm)